# Code::Blocks - GDB не видит точек останова в проекте CMake

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks, gdb

Продолжая знакомиться с Code::Blocks наткнулся на непонятное поведение.
Если проект создан с помощью CMake - GDB не видит точек останова в проекте, так же не работает `выполнить до текущей позиции`..
Выполняет весь код, без остановов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чего пишет на это GDB:

```
Starting debugger: C:\MSVS\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gdb32.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args C:/__BuildSorce/T-CMAKE/t1/winext/codeblock/TestWchar2ext.exe
done
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1
No source file named C:/__BuildSorce/T-CMAKE/t1/test/check_wchar2_MSVC.c.
Temporary breakpoint 3 ("C:/__BuildSorce/T-CMAKE/t1/test/check_wchar2_MSVC.c:150") pending.
Child process PID: 3408
[Inferior 1 (process 3408) exited normally]
Debugger finished with status 0
```

На всякий случай добавил путь к исходнику исполняемого файла, он собственно один, не помогло..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по всему он не может таки найти исходник `check_wchar2_MSVC.c`, как ему еще указать где искать?

Comment: С какими флагами собирается проект в отладочной версии?

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` никаких специфичных вроде не используется, `std c11`

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в конец `-g -Og`. У меня на Qt Creator-е была такая же ерунда, когда он забывал добавлять отладочные флаги.

Comment: спасибо, как окажусь рядом с прибором обязательно попробую.

Comment: @Arhad программа ничего не может "забыть" - это участь людей.

Comment: @Arhad, отлично! именно этих флагов и не хватало, оформите если не трудно как правильный ответ, спасибо.

Comment: По-настоящему нужен только `-g`. Флаг `-Og` просто включает слабую оптимизацию, которая (в отличие от какого-нибудь `-O2`) не слишком мешает отладке.

Comment: Да, согласен, в курсе. И флаг `-ggdb3` мне нравиться больше :). Вот меня более удивило что это не делает само IDE, в отличии скажем от MVC. Такая тривиальная вещь последней приходит в голову.. :)

Comment: Из всех проблем CodeBlocks эта не самая большая. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если отладчик не видит точек останова, значит, информация о них не попала в скомпилированный исполняемый файл.

Для того, чтобы программу можно было отлаживать (а это не только точки останова, но и пошаговая трассировка и просмотр значений переменных), надо передать компилятору следующие параметры командной строки:

- `-g` — снабдить исполняемый файл отладочной информацией, с помощью которой отладчик сможет сопоставить машинные инструкции строкам исходного кода.
- `-Og` — отменить все ранее объявленные `-O`-параметры и включить минимальный набор оптимизаций, не мешающих отладке. Так как Code::Blocks добавляет пользовательские параметры в конец командной строки компилятора, после своих, этот флаг позволяет временно переопределить настройки проекта на время отладки.